# ItemAdded not working when I mail something and I have an Email Enabled List and Mail Subject or Body contains any URL

Tags: event-receivers, email-enabled-library

As checked and found that whenever we put any URL in either the subject or in the body of the mail to send, than neither the entry nor any email notification will receive at my end.
I am using an event receiver and already wrote some code under ItemAdded and ItemAdding method. 
But whenever I mail by putting some url in the subject and mail body then ItemAdded event not fired and the debug is not come to it.
But when I didn't put any url in the subject or in the body the ItemAdded working fine and all the work will done fine.

So, please tell me what to do in this case.